# How to Remove selected item Plist dictionary from UItableview cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, plist

i just created plist programmatically  and inserted bookmark Number now.

How to delete selected item from plist dictionary from UItableview. From commitEditingStyle
i create an array of plist dictionary and display distending order on Uitableview

but when i select delete cell then application creased 
my cresh report :-

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'
```

my plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-      1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>0</key>
<string>5</string>
<key>1</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>2</key>
<string>2</string>
<key>3</key>
<string>6</string>
<key>4</key>
<string>3</string>
<key>5</key>
<string>3</string>
<key>6</key>
<string>1</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

pleae help me how to do that stuff

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you delete the row from your table view the number of rows in section 0 is 7.

```
invalid number of rows in section 0 The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (7).
```

But it should be 6 because you deleted an item.

```
must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).
```

You should check what `-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsForSection:(NSInteger)section` returns. Check if the object you want to delete is deleted from your datasource.

Answer (score 0):

The deleting is done between `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]`, and when you want to delete a row, you must also delete the corresponding object from the dataSource, so you will have the same numbers in both the data source and the tableView